# Google API connexion with PHP 8.1.13 Laravel Framework 10.30.1

Tags: php, google-drive-api, client

I'm currently working on a web application that integrates with Google Drive API. For the last two weeks, I've been able to set up a new client like this and then proceed to my operation :

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]));
$client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'));
$client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'));
$client->refreshToken(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'));
```

It always worked, but now this error appears when I try to interact with the API:

[image: My error : refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken]

I've tried several methods to fix it, but they only led to other problems. Any help would be appreciated.  I'm looking to be able to again make my credential work again.

Comment: What are the other problems you encountered